# How to connect PowerBI desktop to Azure MySQL with SSL

Tags: mysql, azure, ssl, powerbi

I need to set up my connection with PowerBI to Azure Database for MySQL flexible server. I can't seem to find any reliable documentation to do this.

Initially I'm getting this error when I try to connect to the server.

1. Get Data > More > Select MySQL Database
2. Input the Server name and Database name > Hit OK

> **Error**: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while
> --require_secure_transport=ON.

[image]

Then I downloaded the SSL certificate from our Azure portal then successfully imported in the **certmgr.msc** under the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**

[image]

But the same issue persists. Please take note that in this same machine I was able to connect to that server using **phpmyadmin**. In **DbBeaver** as well by simply installing the SSL as a CA Certificate. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to fix my issue by installing the latest mySQL connector and importing a public SSL Certificate.

my machine previously has a **MySQL Connector Net 7.0.2** then I downloaded the latest **8.0.32** from this page: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

thanks to this reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/connect-with-powerbi-desktop

Answer (score 0):

when you import the certificate you get asked to install it for current user or local machine. Have you tried importing it on local machine rather than current user. I have it on local machine and able to connect to the Azure database for mysql server. let me know if it works.

Thanks
Sunitha

Comment: Already tried it. then the error that show up is: 
"An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For information, this isn't really an answer, it would be better as a comment on the original question.